# open map location on image click but some device having Google Map cant open the intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

currently i am using this but(to open map location on image click but some device having GoogleMap cant open the intent) the issue is even device has apps to handle the map intent it wont execute that part

any better way to do this?
like option to select from available apps and no apps to handle that then go for browser

```
 private void openMap()
{
    String Packagename ="com.google.android.apps.maps";

    if (appInstalledOrNot(Packagename))
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=V.V.P.+Engineering+College+Kalavad+Road+Virda+Vajadi,+Rajkot");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(intent);

    }else
    {
        try {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://goo.gl/maps/ETVvFWw453CoeBHs9"));
            startActivity(myIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Map application not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: `currently i am using this` to do what?

Comment: `if (appInstalledOrNot(Packagename))` So you are complaining that that function -of which you did not post the code- always returns false. And looking at the name of it it should always return true indeed.

Comment: no its inbuilt function from android

Comment: by the way issue is solved     dont know how  code is same 
device i was testing had some issue